# remove '/n' from code

Tags: python, string

So I want to remove the '\n' from the end of all parts of file_string. There is an exception, the last value doesn't seem to have '\n'. Here is my code:

```
class Code(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def open_file(self,file):
        infile = open(file, 'r')
        self.infile = infile.readlines()
    def run(self,file):
        self.file_string = []
        self.open_file(file)
        for i in self.infile:
            self.file_string.append(i)
        return self.file_string
```

Like I said, all I need is \n removed.

Input:

```
>>>a = Code()
>>>a.run('go.txt')
```

Current output:

```
['100\n', '200\n', '300\n', '400']
```

What I want:

```
['100', '200', '300', '400']
```

Comment: Also, did you really mean `__inti__`, or is that a typo for `__init__`?

Comment: `rstrip()` removes `\n` (newlines) from the end of a line.

Comment: `rstrip('/n')` would remove a forward slash followed by an 'n' if that's what OP really wants

Comment: would I put rstrip('/n') after append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method:

```
    for i in self.infile:
        self.file_string.append(i.strip())
```

There are also `.lstrip()` and `.rstrip()` variants if you would like to only strip whitespace off the left or right side.